# Creating a Distributable Tarball from a Node.js Project

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg-v3

I have a complex monorepo containing a yarn workspace with multiple libraries and backend services with interdependencies but thankfully nothing circular. I wish that I could actually do the correct thing and decouple/separate all of these into their own Git repositories, but I cannot do that at this point.

I'm using the latest `yarn` release, and the libraries/services are written in TypeScript and transpiled, and everything 'works' right now. Transpiled files are copied into a local `dist` directory for each service.

The build process takes an extremely long time and requires a massive filesystem cache, which again, sadly, I cannot do anything about at the moment. Additionally, due to the situation, creating a Dockerfile which does not simply do `COPY . .` (with appropriate `.dockerignore`s) would result in an extremely brittle setup and an extremely long build time, so in order to reduce complexity, I've decided that in the short term, the most time-effective solution for now is to:

1. run the build step exactly once
2. produce a tarball containing the transpiled JS files, config files, and all dependencies for each service in an included `node_modules` folder.
3. save the built tarball as an artifact in the GitHub Actions CI job which performs `yarn install` and `yarn run build` for the service.
4. in my Docker build step, grab the tarball from the build step, `COPY` it into the Docker build and extract it.

I know very well that most, if not all, of these things are *not* the way to generally do it, but sadly I cannot do anything about it at the moment.

I have been having trouble learning *how* to create such a tarball, as I have multiple `node_modules` folders and workspace dependencies, so I have `service/${service_name}/node_modules`, which is for some reason only 30 MiB, and `node_modules` at the root of the repository which is 2 GiB.

I've been searching high and low for a way to create a simple tarball using only the dependencies needed by the application, and I'm a bit confused as to why this hasn't been done much; perhaps it's because my use case is highly contrived.

Is there a `yarn` command or perhaps some other tooling in the Node.js space which can help me create a tarball with everything (except for Node.js itself of course) that is needed to run my application? Alternately I can use a `Makefile`, but I'm having trouble weeding out unnecessary dependencies and not creating 2-3GiB tarballs. I know that there will be compiled native libraries that must match the architecture, operating system, and distribution, so I'm aware of that hurdle.

Comment: By "unnecessary dependencies", do you mean you're trying to ship only your production runtime dependencies, and not your development-time dependencies?